# setting the keys of one assocative array from the values of normal array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have one associative array and a normal array 
one is called columns and one is called rows

rows has the key as the row name and the value as the value of the row

for example a_id -> 1

now the column array has nine elements and those values are column names a.a_id 
is one of those 9 values

I need to have the value of the column array set to the corresponding column found in the row array keys keeping in mind they do not match unless the table prefix is taken away

Comment: Could you please add some more info (perhaps a short listing of your two arrays)?  It's not entirely clear what you want to do.  Are you trying to overwrite the value of the `columns` array with a value from `rows`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ArkNie9b - Column array

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ccn77DeX - Row array

Comment: I am trying to take the value of column and use it to overwrite the key within rows (rows is an associative array afiak)

Comment: I also need to make sure the overwrite only happens on keys which match if the table prefix is dropped from the column array value

Comment: trying to overwrite the rows array with the values from columns but not the value of the rows merely the key used to reference the value

Comment: Sorry, still foggy here.  Let me see if I have it right.  You want to update the **key** in `rows` with a **value** from `columns` (with the table prefix stripped)?  It seems that you're not changing anything.  Updating `a_id` with `a_id` doesn't change anything.

Comment: the column value was a.a_id rather than a_id found in the row array, I don't know why I thought it would be a good idea to update the keys in rows if I can just strip the column array using substr() anyway I've fixed the problem by stripping from the column array thank you for your help I appreciate it, and yes you were right in guessing the problem with that last try :P